# Sony, Camera And JSON

Tags: windows, sony-camera-api

I have successfully implemented the Sony Remote API in c# on windows.
It works well with the QX10.
However, I was asked to use the implementation with the DSC-HX90V and the ILCE-5000.
I can locate the camera using SSDP with all three.
I can get camera's Device description xml file.
All is well to this point.

The problem I am having is that the DSC-HX90V and the ILCE-5000 do not like the JSON I send it whereas the QX10 handles it well.

My JSON is assumed to be correct or it would not work with the QX10.
I am using Newtonsoft.Json.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Please provide some code samples you have tried.

Comment: That is a nice thing. Will you post both answer and right problem to your post? So that others will get the help from you

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the problem. the JSon had \r\n in it and the cameras do not like that. I removed the \r\n and I no longer get the bad json error.